# 2sxc allowing Javascript on wysiwyg editor

Tags: 2sxc

We want to move away from DNN html/text and replace with with 2sxc-Content.
But in some pages, it require to have javascript injected into the content.
Exp case: tracking user when clicking the Link on content.

TinyMCE had option for allowing Javascript:
`tinymce.init({ ..... extended_valid_elements : "script[language|type|src]" });`

But we cannot found any information on 2sxc-documentation for configure it, we need it to allowing insert Javascript to wysiwyg.

Right now, we change the Input Type from wysiwyg editor into string/text, and it doesn't look nice for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I know what you're trying to do but it's quite dangerous (XSS, etc.), so let me suggest some alternatives:

1. Use the Snippet App to just inject JS Snippets where needed
2. Create a convention placeholder like `ENABLETRACKING` and make your razor-code replace this when rendering the HTML.

I highly suggest you use the snippet app - see https://2sxc.org/apps/app/snippet-inject-v3-hybrid-for-dnn-and-oqtane